# Get real speaker state on laptop?

Tags: android, speaker, speakerphone

I have a phone app which include a function of speaker detection, and also work sucessfully.
And now I was moving the phone app to the laptop, but since the hardware is totally different(Laptop: speaker only?, Phone: speaker and receiver?), so I always get wrong state from laptop.

SO, is it possible to get the speaker state for laptop by using like `AudioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()` method??